# How synchronized Block In Java works? Variable reference or memory is blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a situation and I need some advice about `synchronized` block in Java. I have a Class Test below:

```
Class Test{
    private A a;
    public void doSomething1(String input){
        synchronized (a) {
            result = a.process(input);
        }
    }
    public void doSomething2(String input){
        synchronized (a) {
            result = a.process(input);
        }
    }
    public void doSomething3(String input){
            result = a.process(input);
    }
}
```

What I want is when multi threads call methods `doSomeThing1()` or `doSomeThing2()`, object "a" will be used and shared among multi threads (it have to be) and it only processes one input at a time (waiting until others thread set object "a" free) and when `doSomeThing3` is called, the input is processed immediately.

My question is will the method  `doSomeThing3()` be impacted my method  `doSomeThing1()` and  `doSomeThing2()`? Will it have to wait if  `doSomeThing1()` and  `doSomeThing2()` are using object "a"?

Answer (score 4):

A *method* is never impacted by *anything* that your threads do.  What gets impacted is *data*, and the answer to your question depends entirely on what data are updated (if any) inside the `a.process()` call.

You asked "Variable reference or memory is blocked?"

First of all, "variable" and "memory" are the same thing.  Variables, and fields and objects are all higher level abstractions that are built on top of the lower-level idea of "memory".

Second of all, No.  Locking an object does not prevent other threads from accessing or modifying the object or, from accessing or modifying anything else.

Locking an object does two things:  It prevents other threads from locking the same object at the same time, and it makes certain guarantees about the visibility of memory updates.  The simple explanation is, if thread X updates some variables and then releases a lock, thread Y will be guaranteed to see the updates only after it has acquired the same lock.

What that means for your example is, if thread X calls doSomething1() and modifies the object a; and then thread Y later calls doSomething3(), thread Y is *not* guaranteed to see the the updates.  It might see the a object in its original state, it might see it in the fully updated state, or it might see it in some invalid half-way state.  The reason why is because, even though thread X locked the object, modified it, and then released the lock; thread Y never locked the same object.

Comment: larg: The process method does not update anything inside object 'a'. The purpose I use synchronized block is I don't want two method doSomeThing1() or doSomeThing2() is executed at the same time. It may cause the service my program is using busy. What I concern is the performance  of each doSomething() method. Could you tell me about that?

Comment: I ask about the variable performance and memory because I want to know that there are any differences if I use the below code                                                                                   doSomething1(String input){ A b= a;
        synchronized (b) {
            result = b.process(input);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your code, doSomething3() can proceed in parallel with doSomething1() or doSomething2(), so in that sense it does what you want.  However, depending on exactly what a.process() does, this may cause a race condition and corrupt data.  Note that even if doSomething3() is called, any calls to doSomething1() or doSomething2() that have started will continue; they won't be put in abeyance while doSomething3() is processed.

Comment: All methods are using same connection in side object 'a'. The doSomething1() and doSomething2() are responsible for processing some kind of transaction that can not be done in multi threading environment so they (individual) can not be executed at the same time with same kind of request. If a doSomething1() is using object a, others doSomething1() have to wait (Will cause dead lock or service is busy). The doSomething3() is for others kind of data. One more thing could you help me to answer is will  doSomething2() working in parallel with  doSomething1()?

Comment: The synchronized portions of doSomething1() and doSomething2() will not run in parallel.

Comment: @LinhNguyen It is advisable to use multiple, dedicated lock-objects for independent operations. Thus these independent operations may run in parallel and also the intent is better documented. Of course, these independent operations must not share mutable data.